# Angular.js Show DIV when radio-input is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want to show a div when a **input-radio** is selected.

```
<div>
  <div class="radio c-radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="specialType" ng-model="vm.specialType.closed" />
      <span class="fa fa-check"></span>First Radio
    </label>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="vm.specialType.closed">
    <label>Day: </label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 radio inputs like this one. I want to show & hide each one when one is checked. I tried with `ng-click='someFunction()'` but it's not working, anyway I dont think it's the best way to do it.

If I check the first radio, and for example, 3rd is checked, I want to hide the one shown and show the first one.

My controller has this variable. My idea was use it for true/false (show/hide) But maybe there is a beautiful and clean solution.

```
vm.specialType = {
  closed: false,        //1st radio
  open: false,          //2nd radio
  ownGuards: false,     //3rd radio
  foreignGuards: false  //4th radio
};
```

Comment: That is already a good solution.

Comment: Ok, but now what? I used to show/hide some `divs` with ng-click() but now I cant.  Maybe something like ng-checked or similar? I dont know

Comment: You should update the post with the rest of the html, the problem might be in the other radio buttons, because this looks fine. Are you sure you are using the same input name for all the radios?

Comment: Im just testing whit the 1st radio. Others dont have ng-show atr.

Comment: did my post answered your question? @JorgeBaumann

Comment: yes and no. I understand your code. But mine is not working yet

Comment: If you post your code, people can help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to only show one div at a time, you could have just one variable telling you which div should be displayed. In that case you only need one model.

For each div, compare the div number with the value of the model to see if you need to show the div. Each radio button, will assign its own value to the model.

```
  <div>
    <div ng-show="vm.which==1"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.which" name="vis" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div ng-show="vm.which==2"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.which" name="vis" value="2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div ng-show="vm.which==3"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.which" name="vis" value="3" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div ng-show="vm.which==4"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.which" name="vis" value="4" />
  </div>
```

I've created [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/l9KB0JmwPiUAI3i6BOAb?p=preview) plnkr, you can see the code there as well.

I just created it with four divs, I believe the best practice is to use arrays and `ng-repeat` to do the work if those divs have something in common.